# Symfony findBy field name

Tags: symfony, doctrine, findby

I have association One `Region` ToMany `Places`.
In `PlacesRepository.php` I have this code:

```
       $allPlacesArray = [];
       foreach ($placeTypes as $placeType){
           if($placeType == 'all'){
               $allPlacesArray = $this->findAll();
           }
           $allPlacesArray = array_merge($allPlacesArray, $this->findBy(['region' => 2]));
       }
       return $allPlacesArray;
   }
```

Now it searches places in region by `id` field.
What I want is to search places in region by field `name` from Region entity, because from client I recieve `name` of region not `id`. I don't understand and can't find how I can do that. I've tried `$this->findBy(['region.name' => 'Республика Крым']`, but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Create special method in Repository and write a query using queryBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone needs an answer to this question.
In repository:

```
public function findAllPlacesInRegion() {
            $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->leftJoin('p.region', 'r')
                ->where('r.name like :region_name' )
                ->setParameter('region_name', 'Республика Крым');
            return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: You should make it reusable by allowing the region to be passed as an argument

Comment: @exepti0n in my code I made it. My answer is just for example.